# Testing Material-UI Textfield select component with jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, material-ui

I am trying to write a test for a simple [Material-UI Textfield select component](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#select). The test should show that selecting an options triggers the corresponding event.

Here ist the component

```
<TextField
    inputProps ={{"data-testid": "testId"}}
    id="TextFieldId"
    aria-label={"TextFieldAriaLabel"}
    select
    label="Files"
    value={limit}
    onChange={handleLimitChange}
    SelectProps={{
        native: true,
    }}
    variant="outlined"
>
     {[{value: 5, label: "5"}, {value: 10, label: "10"}, {value: 15, label: "15"}].map(option => (
     <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
           {option.label}
     </option>
     ))}
</TextField>
```

Selecting the value "10" triggers the call of a function with 10 as an input parameter.

I use jest to write the test. I want to click on the select component to open the dropdown. Then I want to click on one of the options. To prove that the event was triggered, I check if the related function is called with the right argument.
It sound very simple, but I ran into many issues. Most of the issues were related to not finding the elements, since material ui nests different html components. My so far best approach looks like this.

```
testObject.renderResult.getByTestId('testId').click();
testObject.rerender();
jest.runAllTimers();
const dropdown = testObject.renderResult.getByTestId('testId');
within(dropdown).getByText('10').click();
testObject.rerender();
jest.runAllTimers();
expect(mostRecentImports).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10)
```

Jest finds the elements, but the test fails. The component remains in its default, showing the value 5 (not 10). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem in my app. Finally I solved it using this solution I found here: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/322#issuecomment-581650108

Write a simple function that opens the select menu and selects the wanted option:

```js
const selectMaterialUiSelectOption = (element, optionText) => {
    // The the button that opens the dropdown, which is a sibling of the input
    const selectButton = element.parentNode.querySelector('[role=button]');

    // Open the select dropdown
    UserEvent.click(selectButton);

    // Get the dropdown element. We don't use getByRole() because it includes <select>s too.
    const listbox = document.body.querySelector('ul[role=listbox]');

    // Click the list item
    const listItem = within(listbox).getByText(optionText);
    UserEvent.click(listItem);
};

[... in your test]
selectMaterialUISelectOption(getByTestId('testId'), "10")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `findAByDisplayValue` method of `@testing-library/react`

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bydisplayvalue